# gdb backtrace of a core file prints error "no such file or directory"

Tags: c, linux, debugging

While testing a program I hit a segmentation fault which dumped the required core.

I'm using gdb to debug a core file as:
**gdb /path/to/exec path/to/core**

I realized after looking at the core file (and the source code) that the issue is actually a NULL pointer dereference that happened while using the "strcmp" function.

However, the core-file backtrace gives the below error message:

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

#0  __strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:32

32    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.

(gdb) bt

#0  __strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:32

#1  0x00000000004041f1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffced1f8ae8) at main.c:1144

Now this is a weird message that I can't make any sense of. I'm not sure why gdb is printing this message **"../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory"**.

I should be getting some message related to NULL pointer de-reference but instead got this. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error looks mystifying but it is correct. It shows that a NULL pointer de-reference was being made by `strcmp`, which was called from line 1144 of your code.

A segmentation fault refers to trying to access a page of memory that is invalid: its segment is mapped as Invalid for read or write in the MMU. In this case, `strcmp` is trying to access page 0 because you passed it a NULL ptr. Null Ptr is address zero, and page 0 is an invalid page.

The reference to file:

```
../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S
```

is referring the the assembler file (.S) that implements strcmp for x86 on 64-bit architectures. Since you do not have that implementation file on your system, gdb is complaining that it can not access it.

Comment: I see. But why should there not be an implementation file? This error is indeed weird.

Comment: Because like most people, you downloaded Ubuntu (or some other Linux), rather than building it yourself from scratch. You can download the source files for Linux, but most people have no need to do so.

Comment: So if I download the source files, then I should no longer see this error?

Comment: As such I'm convinced with your answer and I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @paratrooper, Yes, it would resolve this error, but the error is related to gdb trying to get more information, it is not your error. To focus on your program, be sure to compile with the -g option to get all the debug info related to your own code, stored within the executable. Unless you are trying to optimize for code size, I would always use the -g option in my makefile.

Comment: Just to confirm, yes I actually did download Ubuntu and did not build it from the scratch just like you mentioned. I'm already compiling with -g option. So that should give the info I want. Thanks for these clarifications.

Comment: @ScottK i had the same error for another program and I still have the same error after I build the executable file by myself.

Comment: @Kyrol Please submit your code to a new question complete with a minimal complete compilable example code, and output info (in this case, you invoking your code and then the resulting stack exception traceback). Point to it here, and I will be happy to look at it for you, and would the rest of the community.